# How do I make a video with a gift image background in FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am try this code but I get an error:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i test.gif -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,format=yuv420p" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

[image]

My error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the loop count in the GIF is infinite, then use

```
ffmpeg -ignore_loop 0 -i test.gif -i input.mp4 
       -filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,format=yuv420p"
       -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Thks so muck :) :), My video at center, i want move it to some location (X,Y) on gif image? What is code?? Thks :D

Comment: Replace `(W-w)/2`with X value and `(H-h)/2`with Y value.